# why I do not have transaction when I use aspectJ mode transaction?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-aspects

I have service layer like this:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class TransactionService {

    @Autowired
    private TransactionDao dao;


    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void A() {
        ...
        B();
    }
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED_NEW)
    public void B() {
        dao.save()
    }

}
```

with this config:

```
<property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
</property>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<property name="jpaProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${show.sql}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
    </props>
</property>
```

**Everything woks fine! Because of I have proxy based transaction, new transaction is not created in method B()! But one transaction is created well! Everything is logically!**

**But what about this?**

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" mode="aspectj" />
```

This should fix my problem, new transaction must be created! but I have such error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ name ] in context with path [/name-services] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No transactional EntityManager available] with root cause
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No transactional EntityManager available
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:273)
```

Comment: Using mode aspectj requires either compile or load-time weaving. It isn't a simple matter of toggling the mode it requires more.

Comment: I found tutorials, they do not use any weaving.
https://hop2croft.wordpress.com/2011/07/06/jpa-basic-example-with-entitymanager-spring-and-maven/

Comment: Yes they do... That is enabled by the `spring-configured` tag as that also requires weaving. It will not work without weaving else you have to use proxies.

Comment: is spring-configured annotation enough?  What does it do? Do not I need  to implement my Aspects (before/after method execution?) and etc?

Comment: You don't need to implement anything... You need to either use compile time weaving for the spring aspects or lead-time...

Comment: if i change proxy to aspectJ what differences will I have to transactions? Only the one, which problem I had?